# Javascript time control?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

first press a key before produced code. after second press not produce code. after 18 hour.
how can I do ?

my html code

```
 <p id="demo" name="code"></p> 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()" id="gonder">kodu   goster</button>
```

my javascript code..

```
     <script>
    function myFunction(){
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    var randomValue = randomString(12);
    x.innerHTML=randomValue;
    }
    function randomString(length) {
if ( length <= 0 ) return "";
    var getChunk = function(){
    var i, //index iterator
        rand = Math.random()*10e16, //execute random once
    bin = rand.toString(2).substr(2,10), //random binary sequence
        lcase = (rand.toString(36)+"0000000000").substr(0,10), //lower case random string
        ucase = lcase.toUpperCase(), //upper case random string
        a = [lcase,ucase], //position them in an array in index 0 and 1
        str = ""; //the chunk string
    b = rand.toString(2).substr(2,10);
    for ( i=0; i<10; i++ )
        str += a[bin[i]][i]; //gets the next character, depends on the bit in the same position as the character - that way it will decide what case to put next
    return str;
    }
    str = ""; //the result string
    while ( str.length < length  )
    str += getChunk();
    str = str.substr(0,length);
    return str;
    }
     </script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [javascript timing functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers)? Your javascript code seems related to random number generation.

Comment: may be .I don't know. I am looking for javascript timing function. 
Yes my javascript code random number generation.
I want to generation second press button after 18  hour.